# How to make vortex fluid simulation?

Tags: fluid-simulation

Good daytime. I'm trying to achieve this type of fluid form, but unfortunately I can't do similar. Do You know some techniques to be more realistic? Thanks.[image]

Comment: i would start with creating a domain, fluid and then add a force field and see whats happening...

Comment: Have a look here: https://youtu.be/WBk7YSfJLOw It's about how to create a tornado. It's an emitter particle system raining top-down and affected by force fields. The particles control a smoke simulation which is finally the tornado.

Comment: Thanks! Fluid simulation combined with particle system is a choice.